# multiple joins with where using prisma nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, prisma

I am trying to write few joins with where using prisma-node js.

```js
where: {
    Account: {
      active: true,
    },
    User: {
      UserNotificationsSetup: {
        aaa: true,
      },
      UserNotificationsFrequencySetup: {
        daily: true,
      },
    },
  },
  distinct: ['accountId'],
  select: {
    Account: {
      select: {
        networkId: true,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Prisma does not like `UserNotificationsSetup`:

> Type '{ aaa: true; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have your relations right within your `prisma.schema` ?

Comment: Hey this should be a comment, just a heads up